# How to synchronise Core Data in Swift with Cloudkit and on many devices

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, synchronization, cloudkit

I have developed an app with core data.
I have many entities and relationships (one to one, one to many, ...)
So my app works great but now I would like to synchronise my core data model with cloudkit on many devices.
I have read many things but none of then are clear enough for me.
Do you know how I must proceed?
Do you think that the solution is using Seam :
[enter link description here](https://github.com/nofelmahmood/Seam)
Or ensemble:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles)
Or anything else?
Thank you.

Comment: Seam is good solution as I think so

Comment: Thank you, and do you know where I can find a good tutorial?

Comment: you can use Seam's Demo/Example application as Reference.

Comment: Thank you I will have a look.

Comment: I have many issues with Seam. Does anyone know another solution for synchronise core data?

Answer (score 0):

After many tests I recommend to use Ensembles :

[Ensembles Framework](https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles)